# Use jQuery to Compare a class inside an ID against another class inside an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been coding for ~60+ hours the past 5 days, so I apologize if, due to burn-out, this question is too trivial :-)

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="blah1_1">
  <label for="blah1_1">
    <span class="inner">hi</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="blah1_2">
  <label for="blah1_2">
    <span class="inner">yes</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="blah2_1">
  <label for="blah2_1">
    <span class="inner">yes</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="blah2_2">
  <label for="blah2_2">
    <span class="inner">no</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

All I want to do is use jQuery to:

1.) Get the CSS-equivalent value of "#blah1_1 .inner". I tried:

```
    alert ( $("#blah1_1 .inner").val() );
```

but fail.

2.) Compare `#blah1_1.inner` value to `#blah2_1.inner` value. If equal, then echo a confirmation.

3.) Double loop through the `blah1_*` "Array" and compare it to the blah2_* "array". If `blah1_[x] = blah2_[y]` then echo a confirmation. For example, compare all the `blah1_*'`s against `blah2_1` ... then compare `blah1_*`'s against `blah2_2`, etc.

A little late-night/red-eye help, please? (TIA!)

Comment: i dont see blah1_* array

Comment: [Minimum effort please](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+span+value+in+jquery)

Comment: @MrKhan when the prefix this the same then it can turned into an array

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava that works for (1) & (2) but doesn't solve (3) - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `alert ( $("#blah1_1 .inner").val() );` should `alert ( $("#blah1_1 .inner").text() );`

then you can use [Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select both sets `blah1_*` and `blah2_*`

then use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) jQuery method to iterate over the labels:

then for the compare:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const elms1 = $('[id^="blah1"]');
  const elms2 = $('[id^="blah2"]');
  
  const labels1 = elms1.find('label');
  const labels2 = elms2.find('label');
  
  labels1.each(function(index1, el1){ 
    labels2.each(function(index2, el2){
      console.log($(el2).text() === $(el1).text())
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="blah1_1">
  <label for="blah1_1">
    <span class="inner">hi</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="blah1_2">
  <label for="blah1_2">
    <span class="inner">yes</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="blah2_1">
  <label for="blah2_1">
    <span class="inner">yes</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="blah2_2">
  <label for="blah2_2">
    <span class="inner">no</span>
  </label>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: ... with a mic drop! WOW that's some crazy ninja skillz, thank you! It's taken me a day to plug that into the actual code - didn't even realize ^= was a thing (but loving it!). This is definitely the answer, and to add some spice, I needed to go up a level and if el1.text = el2.text then add a class to elms1 (aka blah1_2). Did that inside the if with jQuery(labels1[index1]).parent().addClass('someClass');